# Two HTML inputs with same Id and Name solve dynamically

Tags: html, jscript

As you can see i want to have two or more inputs with samo Id and Name, but HTML doesn't allow that, so how can i solve this on some other way and how to make active button change it's color

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding = "0" style="font-size:x-small">        
            <tr valign="bottom" style="height:10px">
               <td width="30px" style="vertical-align: top">
                </td>
                <td width="30px" style="vertical-align: middle" align="center" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <label style="font-size:small">
                        Time period</label>

                    <input type="hidden" id="ReportParameter" value = "1" name="ReportParameter" />       
                    <input class="button" id="showDailyReport" name="searchQueue" type="submit" value="Day" onClick="onClickHandler(this)" />

                    <input type="hidden" id="ReportParameter" value = "2" name="ReportParameter"/>       
                    <input class="button" id="showWeeklyReport" name="searchQueue" type="submit" value="Week" onClick="onClickHandler(this)" />

                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

Comment: use it as an array, so name="ReportParameter[]"

Comment: Use a script to change the active button's color if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: can you help me with the script ?

Comment: it is meaningless to have more than one input control with the same name and id. Though there are ways to manipulate it, but you are violating the fundamentals

Comment: To change the colors for the active button, you can use the :active selector

Comment: I cannot use just :active selector because i have button selector with some css  <input class="button" id="showWeeklyReport" name="searchQueue" type="submit" value="Week" onClick="onClickHandler(this)" />

Comment: as @dwhite.me said you can use array for same ID and perform operation

Comment: ok have someone idea how to use Array for ReportParameter and put it in the <input or how to write some script ?

Comment: Simply reference the input as **name="whatever[]"**, note the "[]", and then in your favourite server side handling, use a foreach statement so in PHP- **<?php foreach ($_POST['whatever'] as $whatever){/*Do something with each whatever[]*/} ?>** NOTE, you don't need to use foreach, this is one example. You can do what you like with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define specific class for every button and do the visual changes on that class
ex

```
<input class="button button-red" id="showDailyReport" name="searchQueue" type="submit" value="Day" onClick="onClickHandler(this)" />
```